# How to get Unique Opens with CiviCRM API?

Tags: api, email

I am getting summary report of email by using CiviCRM API but not able to get the field `Unique Opens` I can see on the report page.
Currently I am using this query:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'stats', [
  'mailing_id' => 10,
]);
```

And this gives me these columns:

```
{'Delivered': '1', 'Bounces': '0', 'Unsubscribers': 0, 'Unique Clicks': '0', 'Opened': '1', 'clickthrough_rate': '0%', 'opened_rate': '100%', 'delivered_rate': '100%'}
```

But not the `Unique Opens` which I need too.

Example email report page:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing is_distinct=1 as a parameter in api? It would show unique clicks and opens

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'stats', [
  'mailing_id' => 12,
  'is_distinct' => 1,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you Pradeep